# WPF icons for file type appearing blurry

Tags: wpf

When getting an icon from the OS using SHGetFileInfo and converting it to a BitmapSource it is appearing blurry. How can I prevent this?

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="IconBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="None" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string path, UInt32 attrs, ref SHFILEINFO info, UInt32 size, UInt32 flags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttrs;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string displayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string typeName;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string filename = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Shell32.DLL";

        SHFILEINFO info = new SHFILEINFO();
        IntPtr res = SHGetFileInfo(filename, 0, ref info, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info), 0x101);

        BitmapSource src = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(info.hIcon, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        image.Source = src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried add into the `Image` `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"`?

Comment: @bars222 - Tried it now - no difference sorry

Comment: When calling `SHGetFileInfo`, `0x101` will retrieve a 20x20 icon, while `0x100` will return a 40x40 icon.

Comment: @jstreet That is not correct - I set a breakpoint on the line where the BitmapSource is created in code and can quite clearly see that it is a 16x16 image. However, even if you were correct, it shouldn't matter - I removed the fixed width&height from the Image control and it still comes out blurry.

Comment: Incidentally, to those who continue to bring up the small icon/large icon difference. When I run it with 0x100 and get a large icon, I do get the large version and it is still blurry.

Comment: I meant to say those resolutions are for the the bitmap, not the icon. I get those values in a Windows 10 machine.  If you had mentioned in your post the things you have tried already, people would not be, incidentally, bringing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set UseLayoutRounding="True" in your window declaration.

```
Window x:Class="IconBug.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" UseLayoutRounding="True" >
```

Comment: I will award you the bounty as soon as I'm allowed to. You are right, even though what you write is directly contrary to the documentation for UseLayoutRounding - I quote "If UseLayoutRounding cannot be set at the root, set SnapsToDevicePixels on the child to obtain the effect that you want." So the SnapsToDevicePixels should have had the same effect, but for some reason didn't for the Image control. This is very strange, but thank you.

Comment: By the way, you may also set UseLayoutRounding="True" to the Image itself, no need to bother Window with this setting.